# Date range in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to get date range between from and till in Rails seed.

When I try to generate date range ((Date.today - 10)..Date.today) exception occurred.

Exception message: **bad value for range**

But in the Rails Console everything all right.

I think ActiveSupport  are reasonable for that (my debugger told me that).

Ralls 3.1.3

What's going on?

Comment: This can be done! There are a bunch of edge-cases around stepping through date ranges, but if you're using ActiveSupport from Rails these can be handled elegantly. Check out my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093487/ruby-create-range-of-dates/19094504#answer-19094504 for more details :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can understand what's going on by splitting the two edges and check their class like so:

```
Date.today.class #  => Date 
(Date.today - 10).class # => Date 
((Date.today - 10)..Date.today).each {|d| puts d.class} # => 10 Date works for me
```

The error you're experiencing is something like this:

```
('a'..10) # => ArgumentError: bad value for range
```

Can you post the classes of your 2 edges of the range?

```
(Date.today - 10).class => ?
Date.today.class       => ?
```

Have you overwritten any class in your rails environment? Does it work in `irb`?

PS: As you're in rails you can use `10.days.ago` but you'll need to use `to_date` as it's a `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`

Comment: Class of edges is Date, really.

Comment: I believe you, but try anyway `((Date.today - 10).to_date..Date.today.to_date)`

Answer (score 7):

```
begin
  ((Date.today - 10)..Date.today).each { |date| puts date }
rescue
  $! # => #<NameError: uninitialized constant Date>
end

require 'date'
((Date.today - 10)..Date.today).each { |date| puts date }
# >> 2012-04-06
# >> 2012-04-07
# >> 2012-04-08
# >> 2012-04-09
# >> 2012-04-10
# >> 2012-04-11
# >> 2012-04-12
# >> 2012-04-13
# >> 2012-04-14
# >> 2012-04-15
# >> 2012-04-16
```