# Ruby: Create range of dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for an elegant way to make a range of datetimes, e.g.:

```
def DateRange(start_time, end_time, period)
  ...
end

>> results = DateRange(DateTime.new(2013,10,10,12), DateTime.new(2013,10,10,14), :hourly)
>> puts results
2013-10-10:12:00:00
2013-10-10:13:00:00
2013-10-10:14:00:00
```

The step should be configurable, e.g. hourly, daily, monthly.

I'd like `times` to be inclusive, i.e. include `end_time`.

Additional requirements are:

- Original timezone should be preserved, i.e. if it's different from the local timezone, it should still be maintained.
- Should use proper advance methods, e.g. Rails `:advance`, to handle things like variable number of days in months.
- Ideally performance will be good, but that's not a primary requirement.

Is there an elegant solution?

Comment: I don't think that is any better than that (hopefully someone will prove me wrong). The best I can guess is encapsulate in a method with a meaningful name, or add it do `DateTime` class if you like to monkey patch base clases.

Comment: There must be a way to do it, my code need to change because it does the wrong thing.  I'd like something elegant, i.e. not having to manually fiddle the dates to prevent rounding issues.

Comment: maybe the real problem lies in why you need this array in first place? Just an idea, look at your code and rethink it...

Comment: I don't need an array, but I do need a reliable way to get a range of datetimes.  So the core problem still exists. I'll update the title.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. `(start_time..end_time)` is a range of dates (actually they are times) already. Are you asking how to iterate over it using a configurable step?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using [@CaptainPete's base](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19094504/4575793), I modified it to use the `ActiveSupport::DateTime#advance` call. The difference comes into effect when the time intervals are non-uniform, such as `:month" and ":year"

```
require 'active_support/all'
class RailsDateRange < Range
  # step is similar to DateTime#advance argument
  def every(step, &block)
    c_time = self.begin.to_datetime
    finish_time = self.end.to_datetime
    foo_compare = self.exclude_end? ? :< : :<=

    arr = []
    while c_time.send( foo_compare, finish_time) do 
      arr << c_time
      c_time = c_time.advance(step)
    end

    return arr
  end
end

# Convenience method
def RailsDateRange(range)
  RailsDateRange.new(range.begin, range.end, range.exclude_end?)
end
```

My method also returns an `Array`. For comparison's sake, I altered [@CaptainPete's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19094504/4575793) to also return an array:

### By hour

```
RailsDateRange((4.years.ago)..Time.now).every(years: 1)
=> [Tue, 13 Oct 2009 11:30:07 -0400,
 Wed, 13 Oct 2010 11:30:07 -0400,
 Thu, 13 Oct 2011 11:30:07 -0400,
 Sat, 13 Oct 2012 11:30:07 -0400,
 Sun, 13 Oct 2013 11:30:07 -0400]


DateRange((4.years.ago)..Time.now).every(1.year)
=> [2009-10-13 11:30:07 -0400,
 2010-10-13 17:30:07 -0400,
 2011-10-13 23:30:07 -0400,
 2012-10-13 05:30:07 -0400,
 2013-10-13 11:30:07 -0400]
```

### By month

```
RailsDateRange((5.months.ago)..Time.now).every(months: 1)
=> [Mon, 13 May 2013 11:31:55 -0400,
 Thu, 13 Jun 2013 11:31:55 -0400,
 Sat, 13 Jul 2013 11:31:55 -0400,
 Tue, 13 Aug 2013 11:31:55 -0400,
 Fri, 13 Sep 2013 11:31:55 -0400,
 Sun, 13 Oct 2013 11:31:55 -0400]

DateRange((5.months.ago)..Time.now).every(1.month)
=> [2013-05-13 11:31:55 -0400,
 2013-06-12 11:31:55 -0400,
 2013-07-12 11:31:55 -0400,
 2013-08-11 11:31:55 -0400,
 2013-09-10 11:31:55 -0400,
 2013-10-10 11:31:55 -0400]
```

### By year

```
RailsDateRange((4.years.ago)..Time.now).every(years: 1)

=> [Tue, 13 Oct 2009 11:30:07 -0400,
 Wed, 13 Oct 2010 11:30:07 -0400,
 Thu, 13 Oct 2011 11:30:07 -0400,
 Sat, 13 Oct 2012 11:30:07 -0400,
 Sun, 13 Oct 2013 11:30:07 -0400]

DateRange((4.years.ago)..Time.now).every(1.year)

=> [2009-10-13 11:30:07 -0400,
 2010-10-13 17:30:07 -0400,
 2011-10-13 23:30:07 -0400,
 2012-10-13 05:30:07 -0400,
 2013-10-13 11:30:07 -0400]
```

Comment: Seems like you're not using the block parameter. Should that be removed?

Answer (score 19):

No rounding errors, a `Range` calls the `.succ` method to enumerate the sequence, which is not what you want.

Not a one-liner but, a short helper function will suffice:

```
def datetime_sequence(start, stop, step)
  dates = [start]
  while dates.last < (stop - step)
    dates << (dates.last + step)
  end 
  return dates
end 

datetime_sequence(DateTime.now, DateTime.now + 1.day, 1.hour)

# [Mon, 30 Sep 2013 08:28:38 -0400, Mon, 30 Sep 2013 09:28:38 -0400, ...]
```

Note, however, this could be wildly inefficient memory-wise for large ranges.

---

Alternatively, you can use seconds since the epoch:

```
start = DateTime.now
stop  = DateTime.now + 1.day
(start.to_i..stop.to_i).step(1.hour)

# => #<Enumerator: 1380545483..1380631883:step(3600 seconds)>
```

You'll have a range of integers, but you can convert back to a `DateTime` easily:

```
Time.at(i).to_datetime
```

Comment: Very nice, @kwarrick. 'Not a one-liner but,..'. If you just had to have one, I think this would work: `(0..1.0/0).inject([start]) {|dates,i| dates.last >= stop - step ? (return dates) : dates << dates.last+step}`

Answer (score 15):

## Add duration support to `Range#step`

```
module RangeWithStepTime
  def step(step_size = 1, &block)
    return to_enum(:step, step_size) unless block_given?

    # Defer to Range for steps other than durations on times
    return super unless step_size.kind_of? ActiveSupport::Duration

    # Advance through time using steps
    time = self.begin
    op = exclude_end? ? :< : :<=
    while time.send(op, self.end)
      yield time
      time = step_size.parts.inject(time) { |t, (type, number)| t.advance(type => number) }
    end

    self
  end
end

Range.prepend(RangeWithStepTime)
```

#### This approach affords

- Implicit support for preserving time-zone
- Adds duration support to the already-present `Range#step` method (no need for a sub-class, or convenience methods on `Object`, though that was still fun)
- Supports multi-part durations like `1.hour + 3.seconds` in `step_size`

This adds support for our duration to Range using the existing API. It allows you to use a regular range in the style that we expect to simply "just work".

```
# Now the question's invocation becomes even
# simpler and more flexible

step = 2.months + 4.days + 22.3.seconds
( Time.now .. 7.months.from_now ).step(step) do |time|
  puts "It's #{time} (#{time.to_f})"
end

# It's 2013-10-17 13:25:07 +1100 (1381976707.275407)
# It's 2013-12-21 13:25:29 +1100 (1387592729.575407)
# It's 2014-02-25 13:25:51 +1100 (1393295151.8754072)
# It's 2014-04-29 13:26:14 +1000 (1398741974.1754072)
```

#### The previous approach

...was to add an `#every` using a `DateRange < Range` class + `DateRange` "constructor" on `Object`, then convert the times to integers internally, stepping through them in `step` seconds. This didn't work for time zones originally. Support for time zones was added but then another issue was found with the fact some step durations are dynamic (eg `1.month`).

Reading [Rubinius' `Range` implementation](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/range.rb) it became clear how someone might add support for [`ActiveSupport::Duration`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb); so the approach was rewritten. Much thanks to Dan Nguyen for the `#advance` tip and debugging around this, and to Rubinius' implementation of `Range#step` for being beautifully written :D

#### Update 2015-08-14

- This patch [was *not* merged into Rails/ActiveSupport](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/21192). You should stick to `for` loops using `#advance`. If you're getting `can't iterate from Time` or something like that, then use this patch, or just avoid using `Range`.
- Updated patch to reflect Rails 4+ `prepend` style over `alias_method_chain`.

Comment: This turns out not to work because it doesn't respect timezones, if the original timezone is not the same as the local timezone, the result is in the local timezone.

Comment: @Stefan Well spotted. Just edited in timezone support using `utc_offset` from the range's `begin` property.

Comment: Will this handle variable number of days if the step size is block?

Comment: @DanNguyen don't quite know what you mean there, but it'd be easy for us to find out; can you write an example of how this might look using 'variable number of days'? We're using `Range`'s built-in step function which creates a fixed-step enumerator. So the enum returned will always step by `step` days. Does that answer the question?

Comment: I asked a pretty nonsensical question there :)...what I meant was, does the enumerator work when the step size is **variable** days, such as months and years. If a user is expecting "monthly" to get them back Oct. 10, Nov. 10, Dec. 10, your code won't accomodate that without using Rails `advance`. Here's a modification of your code and its results: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19346914/160863

Comment: Thanks Dan, very well spotted! I've updated the answer to use `advance`. I've re-thought the approach a bit, introducing less methods and keeping with the `Range` API where possible, which is everywhere it turns out. Well, thanks for the help :)

Comment: I apologize for stealing credit for the answer. Your answer was 95% of it, I added 5% of ungraceful Rails clutter.

Comment: You're forgetting that you both found and solved _all_ the bugs :D I think we came up with a nice solution; only a few tests away from an ActiveSupport pull-request really...

Comment: FYI - when seeking month intervals and dealing with a leap year, this comes up one day short in the last interval. I'm not sure of the right way of dealing with the extra day, but you can try it with `1.year.since(Time.parse('2015-06-30 01:42:55 UTC')`.  I've been putting the smallest of remainders/rounding in the last interval (I round to 5 decimal places), perhaps adding a day to the last interval is the easiest, though that may be too inaccurate for some.

Comment: Nearly 2 years later this might become a thing! https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/21192

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to use `uniq` method. Consider examples:

```
date_range = (Date.parse('2019-01-05')..Date.parse('2019-03-01'))
date_range.uniq { |d| d.month }
# => [Sat, 05 Jan 2019, Fri, 01 Feb 2019]
date_range.uniq { |d| d.cweek }
# => [Sat, 05 Jan 2019, Mon, 07 Jan 2019, Mon, 14 Jan 2019, Mon, 21 Jan 2019, Mon, 28 Jan 2019, Mon, 04 Feb 2019, Mon, 11 Feb 2019, Mon, 18 Feb 2019, Mon, 25 Feb 2019]
```

Note that this approach respects range min and max

Answer (score 4):

An hour is 1/24th of a day, so you could do

```
d1 = DateTime.now
d2 = d1 + 1
d1.step(d2, 1/24r){|d| p d}
```

`1/24r` is a Rational, more exact than a Float.

Comment: So simple, lovely.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have `n` values evenly spread between two dates you can

```
n = 8
beginning = Time.now - 1.day
ending = Time.now
diff = ending - beginning
result = []
(n).times.each do | x |
  result << (beginning + ((x*diff)/(n-1)).seconds)
end
result
```

which gives

```
2015-05-20 16:20:23 +0100
2015-05-20 19:46:05 +0100
2015-05-20 23:11:48 +0100
2015-05-21 02:37:31 +0100
2015-05-21 06:03:14 +0100
2015-05-21 09:28:57 +0100
2015-05-21 12:54:40 +0100
2015-05-21 16:20:23 +0100
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DateTime.parse` on the start and end times to get a lock on the iterations you need to populate the array.  For instance;

```ruby
#Seconds
((DateTime.parse(@startdt) - DateTime.now) * 24 * 60 * 60).to_i.abs

#Minutes
((DateTime.parse(@startdt) - DateTime.now) * 24 * 60).to_i.abs
```

and so on.  Once you have these values, you can loop through populating the array on whatever slice of time you want.  I agree with @fotanus though, you probably shouldn't need to materialize an array for this, but I don't know what your goal is in doing so so I really can't say.

Answer (score 2):

The [Ice Cube - Ruby Date Recurrence Library](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube) would help here or look at their implementation? It has successfully covered every example in the [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.1)  spec.

```
schedule = IceCube::Schedule.new(2013,10,10,12)
schedule.add_recurrence_rule IceCube::Rule.hourly.until(Time.new(2013,10,10,14))
schedule.all_occurrences
# => [
#  [0] 2013-10-10 12:00:00 +0100,
#  [1] 2013-10-10 13:00:00 +0100,
#  [2] 2013-10-10 14:00:00 +0100
#]
```

Comment: I like this better because I'll probably use IceCube for some scheduling, but I need this functionality in a performance critical area.  I did a quick timing comparison of 10,000 iterations, and the IceCube is 23.9 seconds and the Range extension from @captainpete is 3.2 seconds.  On 1 iteration, the Range extension was 72x faster.

Comment: I performed a benchmark and it appears that the range extension is ultimately only 5.4x faster.  Given that the range extension has a problem with being one day short breaking up months for a leap year, I've decided to switch to this solution and simply rework how often it is called.  IceCube appears well tested, used and maintained.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby standard library `date` has a built-in method `step` that we can use to achieve this:

```rb
require 'date'
array_of_datetimes = DateTime.parse("2021-09-01 13:00:00")
                            .step(DateTime.parse("2021-09-21 13:00:00"), (1.0/24))
                            .to_a
```

Let's break it down so it's easier to read

```rb
require 'date'

start_date = DateTime.parse("2021-09-01 13:00:00")
end_date = DateTime.parse("2021-09-21 13:00:00")

# Date#step expects a number representing a day. 
# Let's convert into an hour
period = 1.0/24 

array_of_datestimes = start_date.step(end_date, period).to_a
```

Output of `puts array_of_datetime`

```sh
....
2021-09-03T17:00:00+00:00
2021-09-03T18:00:00+00:00
2021-09-03T19:00:00+00:00
2021-09-03T20:00:00+00:00
2021-09-03T21:00:00+00:00
2021-09-03T22:00:00+00:00
....
```

**P.S.**
Original question is from 2013, so I tested this using docker image `ruby:2.0.0-slim`. Ruby 2.0.0 was released in 2012 , and it works fine.