# creation of a json with 10 dates

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to see in a 3 json date before the current date and day 6 after the current date.
But I know how to do ca in ruby

ex: 
the date is November 30 I would like to
  2013-11-27, 2013-11-28, 2013-11-29, 2013-11-30, 2013-12-01, 2013-12-02, 2013-12-03, 2013-12-04, 2013 - 12-05
if someone could help me or directed.
thank you in advance.

Comment: Why is the title French when the text is English? Is it because you thought it would compensate for your broken English in the text? (Irrespective of that, your question is not clear.)

Comment: Are you asking how to create a _random_ date within that interval?

Comment: should not the dates are as follows: 2013-11-27, 2013-11-28, 2013-11-29, 2013-11-30, 2013-12-01, 2013-12-02, 2013-12 -03, 2013-12-04, 2013 - 12-05

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Keep working on your English.  You are welcome here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'date'
require 'json'
given_date = Date.new(2013,11,30)
answer = (given_date-3..given_date+5).to_a.to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093487/ruby-create-range-of-dates/19094504#19094504), it seems to answer your case as well, though not quite as elegant as one would wish.

One of the reasons seems to be that Time objects are seconds based and since Ruby 1.9 there is no "simple" way to iterate through them with coarser granularity (such as days). It should be possible to add such a thing as an iterator though.